# Navigate to a Spotify track's page with it autoplaying?

Tags: spotify

Linking to the song with a Spotify URI ie (`href="spotify:track:5hOvK49BB8MKmMm5zM1mJD"`) causes the track to play when all I want is to go to the album page and show the track highlighted.  I've implemented an `event.preventDefault();` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492405/prevent-song-playing-on-uri-link-click), but I'm not sure of what the handler should look like to go to the track page.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a track page — as you see, you actually get to the album page.

To get the behaviour you want, get the track's album and link to that instead.

Comment: Sorry I meant album page.  I've been able to get there thru the track URI as mentioned above, or thru the album's URI.  But I'm still not clear on how to go to the album page and highlight a track.Obviously linking to the track will highlight it (give the row a blue background) on the album page, but it'll also play the track.  I just want the background.